# Accessing Windows from UNIX SAS

Tags: sas

I am running SAS EG which is installed in Windows but have access to GRID in AIX. Now I want to drop some of the files generated in a program (mostly csv) to a windows location.

My first question, is it possible without using fancy X or call system (guessing) routine with just one **libname** or **filename**.

Second question is will it be possible to drop generated files from EG session in the windows directory.

Comment: @close voter(s) - this is certainly a valid question, as it's asking how to do a function in SAS (a programming tool).  It is not a SU type question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SAS/CONNECT licensed, and are able to run a local SAS session as well as the connection to UNIX, you can use PROC UPLOAD or DOWNLOAD, or even better, you can define a libname like so:

```
libname ulib server=unix slibref=work;
```

`server=unix` defines which remote session you are accessing (you may have multiple simultaneously) and `slibref=work` defines which server-side libname you are accessing.  Change both values as needed.  This requires having an open connection to the server (via SAS/CONNECT), and would be executed in your local session.

If you do NOT have SAS/CONNECT licensed, and/or cannot start a local session on your desktop, you have a few options.

First off, if the UNIX server can mount the windows location as a drive, then you can simply write to it as if it were on the UNIX machine.  This is likely if it is on a shared drive on your NAS or similar; however, if by 'windows location' you mean 'on my desktop machine', it's unlikely.

Second, you may be able to use an EG add-on that allows you to do this.  If you're able to install it, it's a simple point and click interface.  It is NOT scriptable in SAS (it may be scriptable via automation, I'm not sure).  Chris Hemedinger made it available in his blog (currelt(http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/06/copy-files-in-sas-eg/); it is called "Copy Files" if that link breaks and you need to search for it.  The blog post has the add-on and instructions for installing it.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have sas / connect installed. Though after using a plethora of server and slibref option, it doesnt seems to work. The error I am getting are ERROR: Libname ULIB is not assigned.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
ERROR 23-7: Invalid value for the SERVER option

Comment: You need to have the right value there.  That will either be defined prior to the `SIGNON` statement, or in some cases in your `autoexec.sas`.  It is defined in the `OPTIONS REMOTE` statement.  For example, I have `OPTIONS REMOTE=UNIX;` defined, so I have `server=unix` in the libref.

Comment: [The documentation for LIBNAME in SAS/CONNECT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/61908/HTML/default/viewer.htm#connreflibdictent.htm) has more information on this.

Comment: Yes Joe. I am going through this. On the other note , If I can trick SAS to think that CEDA is used for csv then I believe it wont be big difficult.

Comment: CEDA refers to how SAS translates datasets not written for the same OS/bitness - ie, when a Win32 workstation opens a Unix created dataset.  It unfortunately doesn't help you transfer files.